# Got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?) on apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, apt

Whenever I do :

> sudo apt-get update

I got the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8094BB14F4E3FBBE
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have been trying to fix this from one day. 
I tried things like:

1. Uncheck dl.google.com/linux.. from other software in settings
2. Trying finding, if I am behind any proxy by command : $echo "https_proxy",  but it shows nothing.
   (I am also confused in deciding that whether it is because of any proxy. And if yes then at which level it is getting apply. i.e, client side of server side, I have a doubt on my router)
3. I also tried this way, wrote the following commands in /etc/apt/apt.conf file 
   /etc/apt$ cat apt.conf

   Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password:192.168.0.1";
   Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password:192.168.0.1";

save them and then try sudo apt-get update, but still doesn't work. Please also explain what I need to write at username and password place. Is that login Id and password of my router or of my ubuntu.

Please help as I am not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this late answer. Actually, in my case, it turns out to be that my router is providing some proxy, who proxy credentials I don't know. I know the basics credentials to login into that, so I asked my service provider to change that router. 
With the new router, I am not facing this issue. But one thing is confirmed that this was the problem with the proxy server and not with OS.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem,
An network proxy was enabled by an chrome extension in my machine,
I removed that extension and problem solved :)

So the conclusion is either it causes by repository error or network proxy errors...

Answer (score 2):

Privacy Pass Extension on the chromium browser was the culprit in my case

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post as comment instead of as answer.

Comment: I tried that first but need 50 rep, I just posted in a hope that i could help somebody